# the same 'find' command does not work depending on path

Tags: bash, find

I need to search all files whose name contain string 'bind' through a mounted usb key (the search should exclude a directory called 'prog/'

Here is the mounted volume:

```
lsblk /dev/sda 
sda      8:0    1 58.6G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    1 58.6G  0 part /run/media/achille/1af1ba16-5f9a-44af-a481-9e8c63d278e1
```

Here is the search root directory in the usb key:

```
ls /run/media/achille/1af1ba16-5f9a-44af-a481-9e8c63d278e1/it0/
linux/
new_order/
prog/
```

it looks like the find command does not work the same way depending on where you are in the path:

```
pwd
/run/media

find ./achille/1af1ba16-5f9a-44af-a481-9e8c63d278e1/it0/ \
-path ./achille/1af1ba16-5f9a-44af-a481-9e8c63d278e1/it0/prog -prune \
-o -type f -iname *bind* -print 2>/dev/null

./achille/1af1ba16-5f9a-44af-a481-9e8c63d278e1/it0/new_order/bash/scripts/kubernetes-vagrant-centos-cluster-master/addon/rook/rook-agent-clusterrolebinding.yaml
```

-> it works but,

```
cd ..;pwd
/run
```

I recall the same working command (see above), and add 'media' between './' and 'achille':

```
find ./media/achille/1af1ba16-5f9a-44af-a481-9e8c63d278e1/it0/ \
-path ./media/achille/1af1ba16-5f9a-44af-a481-9e8c63d278e1/it0/prog -prune \
-o -type f -iname *bind* -print 2>/dev/null
```

-> it outputs nothing !! why?? I just recall the same command one directory further.If I specify the full path it outputs nothing either.

many thanx folks!

Comment: Try adding `-L` to follow symbolic links.

Comment: @ Jack: pb remains; not sure to understand why this switch '-L'; the founded file in the first attempt is not hard/soft linked but thanx indeed.

Comment: make sure $folder is type d because find does not work on symlinks `find $folder -type f -not -ipath '*/prog/*' -iname '*bind*'`

Comment: I finally found the issue: \*bind\* wont work, '\*bind\*' will. Why would it work in the first attempt then ? I dont know. I have been tricked by the fact that usually * works without quoting.

Comment: @ alecxs: thank you indeed.

Comment: depends on content of directory. shell will expand unquoted globs before passing result to find as arguments